# Extend openstack nova api, how to add new resource

Tags: openstack, devstack

We are trying to extend the nova compute API with a new Resource extension.
Similar to the way it is done in this example code:

https://github.com/accelazh/example-nova-exensions/blob/master/nova/nova/api/openstack/compute/contrib/example_resource.py

As made in the example we have added our own Controller class and also added a new "Resource class" that inherit from extensions.ExtensionDescriptor and have a  get_resources method. Since our resource just need a show method our resource class just contains this:

```
name = "Foo"
alias = "os-foo"
namespace = "http://docs.openstack.org/compute/ext/foo/api/v1.1"
updated = "2015-08-11T00:00:00+00:00"
def get_resources(self):
resources = [extensions.ResourceExtension('os-foo',
             FooController())]
return resources
```

To be able to make a call to our new "resource" from command line we have built a matching resource class on the client side.
We can see that the request that is sent from this class seems to be correct and it is sent to this url:

http://192.168.255.194:8774/v2/16c4a399b6ad4c31b683984bd9188817/os-foo/id'
But the request does not succeed and when we look in the logs for nova api we get this message:

> No route matched for GET
>   /b36ac919aca34253aa1fb133044dbf82/os-foo/ubuntu from (pid=51315)
>   **call** /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/routes/middleware.py:103

Thankful for any tip on how we can solve this problem.

We suspect that we have to add our extension to the router some how but we can not find where to do this.
But we can see that os-foo is listed among the other extensions when we do a nova list-extensions

Comment: You might want to task this on the [openstack development mailing list](http://lists.openstack.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/openstack-dev).